# Unable to use the logical OR operator in Firebase Firestore security rules - the condition always evaluates to `false`

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to allow writes to `/companies/{company}` if the logged-in user is a manager **OR** the record doesn't exist.

I have the following security rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    function isManager() {
      return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/managers/$(request.auth.uid)).data.id == request.auth.uid;
    }

    function companyExists(company) {
      return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/companies/$(company));
    }

    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }

    match /companies/{company} {
      allow read: if resource.data.isActive == true || isManager();
      allow write: if !companyExists(company) || isManager();
    }
  }
}
```

There's a problem with the following line:

```
allow write: if !companyExists(company) || isManager();
```

This condition always evaluates to `false` even if the `!companyExists(company)` function evaluates to `true`.

I'm sure that `companyExists(company)` and `isManager()` functions work as expected because I've been testing them separately.

For example, if I use the following rule:

```
allow write: if !companyExists(company);
```

Then the expression evaluates to `true` if the company record doesn't exist. Same with the `isManager()` function. It returns `true` if logged-in user's ID exists in the `managers` collection. The problem appears only when using the `||` operator between two functions.

Comment: How is your frontend code structured? I had a similar problem and the solution was to initialize the firestore binding in the right order

Answer (score 1):

Did not worked:

```
allow read: if request.auth.uid != null || if request.auth.uid == "VacOqosKJhPjxQaCf93wGVjc8Fy2"
```

This way it works:

```
allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
allow read: if request.auth.uid == "GePV7U9kDmfThLVXzks6nn2HgXn2";
```

Comment: Why the first one did not work?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to allow everyone to create a company but only managers to edit them. This can be achieved in a simpler way:

```
match /companies/{company} {
  allow read: if resource.data.isActive == true || isManager();
  allow create;
  allow update, delete: if isManager();
}
```

It will also be cheaper, because you won't need to perform a get request to check if it exists.

Also, logic for isManager could also be rewritten using custom claims instead of a document, that way you could also save another read. That is out of the scope for this question, but if you need more details just post a comment.

Comment: That is true, but the example I posted is oversimplified. In reality, I need to check multiple conditions separated by the `||` operator, so the solution posted by you won't help me.